# Custom store for rallycardboard

Tags: sdk, rally

I'm trying to show on rallycardboard all Tasks with WorkProduct._type==TestSet
but when I try to filter by WorkProduct._type I got an error. Seems like it is not allowed to use _type of a child object as a filter property.
If so, maybe it is possible to use some custom store with CardBoard in sdk 2.0p5, as I normally do with rallygrid. Haven't found store option in CardBoard configs list.
Appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Unfortunately right now it is not possible to hand a precreated store to a CardBoard.  This will hopefully be fixed by the time the sdk is ga'd.